# Make Gin run on some other port

Tags: go, go-gin

I have this in my main.go file

package main

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/someone/something/backend/config"
)

func main() {

    app := config.App()

    env := app.Env
    gin := gin.Default()
    
    gin.Run(":" + env.PORT)
}
```

Where PORT is `8080`.

When I run  `go run main.go` it says `Listening and serving HTTP on :8080`

but when I run `gin run main.go` it says `Listening on port 3000`

How can I change port here? to something else. I need to run something else on port `3000`

Update: `gin run main.go --port 8080`   still logs `Listening on port 3000`.

Update: 2 `gin run --port 8080 main.go` also says listening on port `3000`

Update: 3 `GIN_MODE=debug PORT=8080 gin run main.go` also doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you should first read your Environment Variables in your code and then set it before running your code

```
import (
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/someone/something/backend/config"
)

func main() {


    
    gin := gin.Default()
    
    gin.Run(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"))
}
```

and run your program,

```
 PORT=8080 && go run main.go
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gin` command is related to a different repository `github.com/codegangsta/gin`.

The `GIN_MODE` environment variable has no effect on the `gin` command because it is not related with it. Also changing default port value of it with `PORT` environment variable won't work, because it relies on `-p`,`--port` flags or `GIN_PORT` environment variable to change the default port value of itself.

If you want to change the default value of port for `gin` command you can use either of these options:

Use the `--port` or `-p` flag *following the proper syntax*
or;
Using the environment variable `GIN_PORT` with the desired port as the value (`GIN_PORT=8080`)

*When using the `-p` or `--port` flag, the command syntax is strict and this* **must** *be placed before the command `run`*

example: `gin -p 8080 run main.go` or `gin --port 8080 run main.go`

*NOTE:* Your previous attempts to use `--port` did not have any effect because it was not placed properly in the command's syntax, between `gin` and `run`

To change the port using variables:

First, set the variable, such as `export GIN_PORT=8080` and then running the command `gin run main.go` (you can do this in one command using `export GIN_PORT=8080 && gin run main.go`)

The difference between setting the port via environment variable and setting port with flags is that if you set port with `export GIN_PORT=value`, the program will use this port in place of the program default *unless the `-p` or `--port` flag is used explicitly with the command, which will override the environment variable*.

If you set port with flags, the port will only be changed for that single instance.

Of course you can set `GIN_PORT` in any file you use to set variables with, so that you don't have to set this each time you log in.

**Additional Information**

The `cli.IntFlag` struct initialization located on lines 48-53 in the [main.go of the `gin` command](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin/blob/master/main.go):

```
cli.IntFlag{
            Name:   "port,p",
            Value:  3000,
            EnvVar: "GIN_PORT",
            Usage:  "port for the proxy server",
        },
```

Defines default port value of the `gin` command as well as which flags and which environment variable can change it. `Name` field for the flags. `Value` field for the default value. `EnvVar` field for the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variable PORT:

```
 PORT=8080 && gin run main.go
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`resolveAddress()` function](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/a889c58de78711cb9b53de6cfcc9272c8518c729/utils.go#L140) does check the environment variable:

```golang
func resolveAddress(addr []string) string {
    switch len(addr) {
    case 0:
        if port := os.Getenv("PORT"); port != "" {
            debugPrint("Environment variable PORT=\"%s\"", port)
            return ":" + port
        }
        debugPrint("Environment variable PORT is undefined. Using port :8080 by default")
        return ":8080"
    case 1:
        return addr[0]
    default:
        panic("too many parameters")
    }
}
```

That means, in a Linux-like shell, you should be able to do:

```
PORT=8080 gin run
```

And you can display more logs with:

```
GIN_MODE=debug PORT=8080 gin run
```

---

Regarding your program (the one with your own `main.go`), check the name of your project in your `go.mod`, and try:

```bash
cd /path/to/my/project
go install
which yourAPP # should be /Users/RohitB/go/bin/yourApp
GIN_MODE=debug PORT=8080 yourAPP
```

If you need [`codegangsta/gin`](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin), check with `gin --version` that you did not install by mistake `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`.

Comment: Updated Question with screens but `GIN_MODE=debug PORT=8080 gin run main.go` doesn't give any logs and still shows port 3000

Comment: @anny123 Yes, but `GIN_MODE=debug` should print more details. What does it print? What does `alias gin` return? What does `which gin` return?

Comment: if you look at the updated screenshot in the question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFU5t.png) it doesn't print anything. Same as what it used to print before.

Comment: @anny123 OK. Again: What does alias gin return? What does which gin return?

Comment: `alias gin` doesn't return anything. `which gin` returns `/Users/RohitB/go/bin/gin`

Comment: @anny123 Check you `go.mod` in your project: what version of gin is being used/imported?

Comment: `github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253318/discussion-between-vonc-and-anny123).

Comment: Sir, can i join your chat ?

Comment: @BrokenArmor Sure, if you have access to this chat, leave your question over there. If not, try this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1204/vonc).